# Why other activity is destroying when 'Home' key is pressed.?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, launchmode

There are two activities `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`, both are made `singleTask`. Here *ActivityB* is of category `HOME` and it is set to always. I am starting *ActivityA* from a `BroadcastReceiver` on `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`, it is starting *ActivityA* as expected but when *HOME KEY* is pressed (which is *ActivityB*), *ActivityA* is getting destroyed.
What can be the possible reason of it? How can I stop *ActivityA* from being destroyed? By keeping both activities `singleTask`.

This is the BroadcastReciever:

```
public class MyStartupIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED == intent.getAction()) {

        Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(i);
     }
   }
}
```

And manifest file is as follows:

```
   <activity
        android:name="ActivityB"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="ActivityA"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for making android:launchMode="singleTask" ??

Comment: Yes there are some more activity which will be coming on top of these acitivies, we want to clear all those and get only base activity which are ActivityA and ActivityB.